# LWE: error and float operations

Tags: implementation, lattice-crypto, lwe

### Background

I'm trying to make sense of the error in implementations of LWE and R-LWE.  In LWE and R-LWE error is added to vectors in lattices to make it computationally infeasible to recover any meaningful data.

It was said [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46910/is-there-a-floating-point-csprng) that using float operations in PRNG's aren't reliable enough across different environments.

According to the accepted answer on this [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/uniformly-distributed-secure-floating-point-numbers-in-0-1) though, it's possible to "trivially" generate cryptographically secure, nearly uniform distributions of floating point decimals.

### Questions

1. Does the error used in LWE or R-LWE rely *primarily* on float operations?
2. Do float operations need to be in a finite field to be secure?
3. Before rounding occurs, are all numbers floating decimals?

### Conjectures

My assumption is that Case 1 may be likely, but Case 2 is true.  This leads me to believe that only error terms are treated as floating point decimals as a way to maintain efficiency and security, but taking everything either modulo a number or modulo an ideal generates an integer.  So in effect, the error taken modulo a number produces a lattice point (integer), or error taken modulo an ideal produces a lattice (finite field).

Is this an accurate assessment?

Comment: Sampling a uniformly distributed number in the range $[0,1)$ is different from building a CSPRNG that is built on floating point operations. Being able to do the former does not imply the latter.

Comment: This is one part of my question, yes.  The rest of the question focuses on the specific operations an implementation of LWE or R-LWE requires in order to introduce error securely.

Comment: Isn't the foundation of this question totally flawed?  One of the principal links says you can't do this (para.2), and the other says if you do it won't be any good (para.3).  You can't have a _nearly_ uniformly distributed CSRNG.   Consider the criticism of RC4.

Comment: @PaulUszak The foundation of the question is how error is handled in implementations of LWE and R-LWE *precisely* because of the points you've raised.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any floating points involved in either LWE or Ring-LWE errors. The error vector is an element in Z_q^n or Z_q[x]/(x^n+1), which has small coefficients (compared to q) when lifted to the integers.

Comment: @zhenfeizhang: Well, the construct (r)LWE, as used within cryptography, doesn't involve any floating point values being exchanged.  However, we still have the possibility of whether constructing the 'discrete gaussian' error vectors could be done faster by using floating point internally.  I personally suspect not, but the answer isn't obvious...

Comment: @poncho If the answer isn't obvious, is the opposite?  Would float operations have negative performance costs, or do you feel they would be more or less equal but it's hard to gauge improved performance?

Comment: No, it's not obvious; in addition, performance questions like this would generally depend on the CPU architecture.

Comment: @zhenfeizhang So the error vectors are rounded to negligible sized integers, and then embedded into some n-dimensional matrix, mod q for some prime q, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering point 3, no.  Rounding a floating point number just leads to a floating point number.  It just has less significant digits.  So they're still represented as a significand and exponent.  This is a widely accepted [format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) these days.  An integer is a totally different storage method that does not lead to accumulated errors.  They're 100% precise.  The uniform distribution problem is exacerbated by the gargantuan 24 orders of magnitude variance in precision of floating point numbers as:-

[image: precision variance]

Further arithmetic operations on a rounded floating point number will still accrue rounding errors in difficult to predict ways.  And different languages have different types of numbers.  For example Java has different types of numbers compared to  Perl, and those are different to C /C++.  This contributes to the difficulty of  native random floating point number generators.

It's typical to cast a number from one kind to another if you want to change type.

Comment: Can you address the remaining issues raised in the question?  I understand your answer in the context of float operations and integers, but the main question is how these impact lattice cryptography dealing with error.

Comment: And when you use the term "rounding" do you mean the cross-rounding function used in R-LWE?

Comment: At PQCrypto 2017 Peter Schwab mentioned in passing that they used double-precision...couldn't catch if it was in assembly or not...

https://videos.2017.pqcrypto.org/school/

Peter Schwabe: "Implementation of post-quantum cryptography"
41:10 in.